# AppleScript: How can I quit all running user apps and then restart to bootcamp partition (this part works)?

Tags: macos, applescript, restart, bootcamp

I frequently reboot into Windows on a bootcamp partition in my Mac Pro (e2008) (Mac Os X 10.5.6). Because I like to use the time it takes to reboot for other things instead of just sitting around I'd like to write/execute a simple applescript that would basically do:

1. Quit all running user applications
2. **Then***—after the apps have been quit properly—*restart to my bootcamp partition

Part 2 I have been using for a little while now with a script I found online that is as follows:

```
do shell script "bless -mount /Volumes/WinVista/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" with 
administrator privileges
do shell script "shutdown -r now" with administrator privileges
```

This works great except that if applications are open they are not properly shutdown (basically they are being 'force quit') so I would like to have the script shutdown apps first then execute the reboot.

I have found a similar question on Stack Overflow but since my understanding of AppleScript is virtually none existent I don't know how I could combine this: ([Quit All Applications using Applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495323/quit-all-applications-using-applescript)) with the script that does the reboot.

Is this possible?
If so I would appreciate any advice/help/scripts you can throw at me.

*Also I have virtually no experience with AppleScripting all I have done so far was copy/pasting what I had found online, just in case that matters.*

Thank you for reading.

Jannis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using

```
tell application "Finder" to restart
```

this try to quit every application, while prompting for saves, and then reboot the computer

Comment: +1 I've been using the same script that Jannis posted, but this is a much better way of doing it. I just tried it out, and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how will I automatically tell it to boot into my Windows partitions so I don't have to hold down the ALT key while booting to get to the bootmanager?

Comment: Should this be the script to quit all apps + restart directly to Windows?

    do shell script "bless -mount /Volumes/WinVista/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" with administrator privileges
    tell application "Finder" to restart

Comment: yep, the first part of your script looks good (I think.) It was only the second part that you needed to change

Comment: Thanks again, your line works brilliantly!
This is what I used ultimately:
<START>
display dialog "This script will quit all running application and restart this Mac directly to Windows. 

Do you want to continue?" with icon 2 with title "WARNING: This computer is about to be restarted!"
do shell script "bless -mount /Volumes/WinVista/ -legacy -setBoot -nextonly" password "xxxxxx" with administrator privileges
tell application "Finder" to restart
<END>

Comment: **Sidenote**: A close derivative of this is useful for OS X-targeted shell scripts: `osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to restart'`